# How do I change the text color of the Search the entire Store Here text in search box

Tags: code

I have figured out several places and ways to change the actual text, but can't seem to figure out how to change the color of the text. Any help would be appreciated.

I am pretty new to Magento, I have learned a ton in the last month or so, but I still do not understand how to do a lot of things. I am using Magento 1.9 with a theme called Grayscale Full-width responsive. I know that the text for the search box is located in form.mini.phtml (specific code copied below) - but first I am unclear how to change the color with this format. I tried sticking a #"color code" in but either I am putting it in the wrong place or using the wrong format. Second, I had been hoping there was a way to change it either in styles.css, color.css or local.xml file so that when an update comes along it won't wipe out my changes, since the only place I can find the form.mini.phtml file is under app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/
There is not a similar file in my theme folder, so I am assuming they are defaulting to the base code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[var searchForm = new 
Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__
('Search entire store here...') ?>');searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php 
echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');//]]>
```

I posted an update to this question in the comment below.

Comment: I'm not sure how the question is unclear. I can't figure out how to change the color of the text in the mini-search box in my header. It currently reads: "Search entire store here..." I want to change the color of the text. I don't understand the answer provided by Amit Bera below. I tried adding the code:
     #header-search{color: #08a0ff;}
    #search_mini_form{color: #08a0ff;} into the styles.css and when that didn't work I tried adding it into colors.css - that didn't work either.

Comment: I've solved this myself. Hopefully it will help someone else. This may be what Amit Bera meant with his post. but it wasn't clear to me. If you go to  skin/frontend/default/YourTheme/css/ and open styles.css and add or change this line: .header .form-search input.input-text {float: right;color:#08a0ff;} adding or changing the color to what you want. In my case I had to add the color:#08a0ff; part to this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic,search box is coming from `app>design>frontend>you package >YourTemplate >template>catalogsearch>form.mini.phtml`.

Also search box  id is `header-search`,`search_mini_form` in rwd template . css exit in style.css fil

css change should be work using below code

```
#header-search{/*your css works */}
#search_mini_form{}
```

Comment: I am fairly new to Magento and I am not fully understanding your answer. It seems I have a limit on how many characters I can post in a response, so I will edit my original post with a more full explanation of my issue.